# (PHP,SQL) When using Insert Into .. Select statement I get same row twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

I want to take some data from Tovar_Dosky into Filter1 where value of column "cena" is less or equal to 50. In table Filter1 I gethave only 1 row. But I get that row twice. Any help ? Code:

```
 $sql= "INSERT INTO Filter1(meno, znacka, cena, op, format) 
       SELECT meno, znacka, cena, op, format 
       FROM Tovar_Dosky WHERE cena<=50";
       $result=$conn->query($sql);
        if (!($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)) {
        echo "Error: " .$conn->error;
        }
```

I get no errors from sql.

Comment: Why are you executing the query twice (using `$conn->query($sql)`), rather than just using `$result`?

Comment: i believed you executed it twice and you do not have any constraints between tables.

Comment: Oh so if statement executes query as well. Sorry I am new to sql, didn't know that. Sorry for such a pathetic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Its obvious you are executing the query twice ... Better change your query to below ...

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO Filter1(meno, znacka, cena, op, format) 
   SELECT meno, znacka, cena, op, format 
   FROM Tovar_Dosky WHERE cena<=50";
    if ($result=$conn->query($sql)) {
     //Do what you want with the $result
    }
    else{
     echo "Error: " .$conn->error;
    }
```